# Paging 3 loads all the data at once without scrolling the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

I have an implementation of Paging 3 with network + DB configuration; where the RecyclerView is inside the SwipeRefreshLayout.

I have given the paging config as this.

```
const val API_RESPONSE_DATA_SIZE = 50

    val PAGED_LIST_CONFIG = PagingConfig(
        initialLoadSize = API_RESPONSE_DATA_SIZE * 2,
        pageSize = API_RESPONSE_DATA_SIZE,
        prefetchDistance = API_RESPONSE_DATA_SIZE,
        enablePlaceholders = false
    )
```

for eg: I have a dataset of 700+ items on initial it should ideally call load(0) & load(50) to fetch 100 items. But it is calling load(100), load(150) and so on.... without scrolling the recycler view.